# fadein/fadeout not fading correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fade

I am currently using jquery to fade between div's to be displayed on a page. These functions work perfectly on numerous pages in the same project, and also used to work on the page I am now having issues with.
Here is an example of the working code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btnNew.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("#divView").fadeOut("100",
            function () {
                $("#divAddEmployee").fadeIn("100");
            });
        });
        $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
            $("#divAddEmployee").fadeOut("100",
            function () {
                $("#divView").fadeIn("100");
            });
        });
    });
```

This works just how I want it to, however on the problematic page, the equivelant functions do not operate correctly.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btnNew.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("#divView").fadeOut("100",
            function () {
                $("#divNew").fadeIn("100");
            });
        });
        $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
            $("#divNew").fadeOut("100",
            function () {
                $("#divView").fadeIn("100");
            });
        });
    });
```

This function still effectively toggles the divs, however it no longer actually performs the fade animation. The page looks like it is posting back, however it is not and so should provide a smooth transition by fading. What could have led to this?

Comment: It's worth to mention that `.fadeIn("100")` and `.fadeOut("100")`  are not correct. If you want provide duration of effect in milliseconds, you have to pass `Number`, not `String`: `.fadeIn(100)`. [Error exampe](http://jsfiddle.net/z3af8qxb/). [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/).

Comment: I hadnt noticed, thanks for pointing that out! It is certainly more prominent with the longer timer you provided! Unfortunately, it wasnt the issue.
However, by extending the fade timer, i can see that the divs are staying visible the entire timer then are hidden/appear as the timer finishes

Comment: Yes, it isn't issue, that's for sure. Actually code works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2evc4db/), so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: So through some trial, and some research, i have discovered that it is due to the CSS of the panels within the divs being faded. Apparently the functions have issues when position is set to absolute or fixed. I dont know a way around this that still allows the panels to be centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the CSS and the Jquery combined. An absolute positioned element cannot fade, it can either be shown or not.
My solution was to forget about vertical centering and use another method for horizontal center, whilst this was not quite what I wanted, it was one of the easiest methods of dealing with the issue